# Meteor Iron-Router accessing variables through [data] vs [params]

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

In developing advanced routing and nested templates/data contexts in a Meteor project, I am trying to differentiate between the `data` and `params` components of a route in Iron Router and their best uses.

The goal is to merely pass simple variables/parameters to the template. Which is better, to use `params` or `data`, and what are the major differences or advantages in such a context?

To me the biggest difference seems to be that `data` is available as a data context in the Blaze template, while to access `params` requires passing that variable to the template via an associated helper.

I personally don't like the idea of setting full data contexts (from db queries) in the router config, and would prefer to do that in helpers. So I feel like the easiest way to pass these parameters to the template is actually through the `data` object, saving the extra code having to be written.

However this seems to be against common practice, so I'm looking for anything I've missed as to why this would be the case.

An example using data:

`Router.route('aRoute', {data: {var: "this var"}});`

I can access in template "aRoute":

`{{var}}`

**Versus** Using params:

`Router.route('aRoute', {params: {var: "this var"}});`

I need to create a helper first:

`myVar : function () {return Router.current().params.var};`

Then I can access the object in the template "aRoute":

`{{myVar}}`

Do I have this right? Am I missing anything? If I'm not really using `data` of the router for data contexts (as commonly used), is this pattern appropriate?

Comment: Just to clarify the context: I am merely passing a parameter that flags the template as "editable", so either `params{edit:TRUE}` or `data{edit:TRUE}`are the options I'm looking at. Also I will continue this pattern through future development of the application, so I want to make an informed choice at this point.

Comment: I think I am understanding the distinction between the two as being: `data` is primarily for templating and rendering, while `params` seems best suited for passing parameters to the server for DB queries for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bordering on opinion - the preferred pattern in i-r is to use `data:` to set the data context of the route. This allows the template to consume data in a very standard way including potentially not requiring helpers at all!

When i-r provides the data context the template can behave just like it was nested in another template and provided with a data context - there's no difference. With the `params` approach the template now can only be used on a *matching* route.

Comment: Thanks @michel-floyd. Had not though of your last point regarding on access to data during routes vs not using routes. I think for my specific application, I will use a field in `data` to allow for future non-routing or nesting use of the main templates.